# Install app from App Center in terminal

Tags: pantheon-terminal, appcenter

is it possible (and how?) to install AppCenter Apps (like Quilter or Agenda) via command line? sudo apt install doesn't work for me...

Thanks,
Carlos

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt install name-of-package` is the right way to do it.

One way to go about this is to double-check that you are giving the right package name.

You can look for the desired package/app with: `apt search name-of-package`

If that doesn't work for you then reply with the error that you are getting in terminal.

Cheers

Comment: This is the right answer. Most apps made for elementary have a weird and long name (such as io.github.blablabla) so it's not so straight-forward to guess the name of the package. For example, Quilter is called `com.github.lainsce.quilter`